# New York Times RDF Data Dump or SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I'm trying to query nytimes rdf data. The problem is that I can't find either their rdf data dump nor a sparql endpoint. Wherever I search, they lead me to this page: http://data.nytimes.com/ , which I can't access.

> Network Access Message: The page cannot be displayed

Does anyone know a link to download their .nt file or to their SPARQL endpoint ?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's a resource request, and any response could well be invalid with time, but I wonder if https://datahub.io/dataset/nytimes-linked-open-data has what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no they don't, they lead to data.nytimes.com. It's not mainly a resource request, it's also to check whether I'm the only one who can't access the data repository and when the last time it went offline.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean;  yes, those seem to report 502 Bad Gateway, too.  But an answer about whether that site is up or down will *also* become outdated if the site ever comes back up.  It's not a bad question, but it's not the kind of question for which Stack Overflow is a good fit.

Comment: What about https://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/wiki/NYT_Linked_Data_Corpus ?  It looks like they might have a cache.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks, I'll try download the tdb folder from https://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu//nyt/irs/tdb/ . If it works and the data is complete, I will answer my question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a website that contains a cached copy of almost all the rdf datasets (including nytimes) and in a good format also (hdt): http://lodlaundromat.org/wardrobe/

Answer (score -1):

You can find the Dataset for you URI using http://wimu.aksw.org.
The input is your URI (http://data.nytimes.com/) 
The output are the datasets where this URI was defined, in this case:

http://km.aifb.kit.edu/projects/btc-2010/btc-2010-chunk-304.gz
or
http://139.18.13.76:8082/dirHDTLaundromat/decompressed/b5/b5645a949067b03fd509a892e5ed7a80/b5645a949067b03fd509a892e5ed7a80.hdt

The link for the results:
http://wimu.aksw.org/Find?top=10&urihdt=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.nytimes.com%2F

Hope it helps :)